# Sqlite Expert - Updated multiple tables with same column

Tags: sqlite

First off I'd like to say I'm rather new to Databases and thanks for helping a newbie out.

For a app project I am working on with a friend, I've put together a database with multiple tables that share some of the same column names eg table name is "S18" and column name "trigger". I need to change the text in the column "trigger" from "Soul 1," to "1, Wind" but I have several tables, and rather not update each table at a time. Is there a way I can process everything at once? Or am I doomed to do all of this one table at a time?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on what tools you have access to. I'm fairly certain there is not a way to update all columns with the same name without mentioning the table name. If you can use C# or another programming language however, you can find a way to do that programmatically.

You can get a list of all the tables using the statement:

```
select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name not like 'sqlite_%'
```

("sqlite_master" is a table that stores information about the database. Any tables that start with "sqlite_" are system tables so you probably don't want to mess with those.)

Then you can cycle through that list getting all the column names by doing this command:

```
PRAGMA table_info('tableName')
```

When iterating through the tables and columns, you can store those table names and columns names.  Then it is a matter of searching through your data for the specific column names that you want to update.

That being said, it will be up to you if you think it is worth the time.

Comment: Yeah so I need to refer to each table, I ended up writing out a find / replace command and just changed the table for each one.. wish there was a better way, but it didn't take too long